# ESP8266-01 Does not receive or respond to AT Commands

Tags: firmware

I have an ESP8266 wifi module that I want to test, to use it later. I uploaded the original Espressif AT firmware "ESP8266 AT Bin V1.7.0" from: https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at.

FTDI seems to be connected to the ESP all properly, since firmware upload successfully finished and prompted:

> Leaving... 
>   Hard resetting via RTS pin...

I use the Arduino IDE's serial monitor at 115200 baud rate set to "both NL & CR", to send the commandS "AT", "AT+GMR" e.t.c.

No response ever returns. I have no idea about what am I doing wrong, or why esptool.py can connect to the board smoothly but there is a problem with sending AT commands to it.

Thanks for all suggestions in advance. Please comment if you need any other information about the issue.

P.S: I have two modules bought at different times. Both of them wont work with AT commands.

Comment: Try 76800 baud rate - A couple of my esp boards needed this - You can change the rate permanently if needed

Comment: how did you flash it? the bin on the Espressif download is for 2MB module (yes, strange). Flash Download Tool can upload it right to 4 MB module, but esptool can't. and how do you power the module?